# CSS Masks, correct property to use CSS.supports to detect support for?

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing a prefix-appending PHP script so people who use CSS with the software I'm working on will never have to worry about prefixes. Unfortunately I haven't had the chance to work with every single possible CSS property/value in existence so I'm not sure which property to use for `CSS.supports` (`background` is used in the example below)? Just to make it not a point in comments, I'm doing this for `-khtml-`, `-o-`, `-moz-`, `-webkit-` and -`ms-` for the project, I just so happen to be working on the Chrome/Safari forks of Webkit/blink engine currently.

```
alert(
CSS.supports('background','clip-path')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','clip-rule')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-image')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-mode')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-repeat')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-position')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-clip')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-origin')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-size')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-composite')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border-source')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border-mode')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border-slice')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border-width')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border-outset')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border-repeat')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-border')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask-type')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','mask')+'\n'+

CSS.supports('background','-webkit-clip-path')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-clip-rule')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-image')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-mode')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-repeat')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-position')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-clip')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-origin')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-size')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-composite')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border-source')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border-mode')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border-slice')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border-width')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border-outset')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border-repeat')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-border')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask-type')+'\n'+
CSS.supports('background','-webkit-mask')
);
```

Comment: The reason prefixes are used is that the technology they refer to is under development and the API can (and sometimes does) change. See [this link](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) for discrepancies relating to an early prefixed Mozilla implementation for example.

Comment: @MikeW I understand and advocate *for* prefixes but thanks.

Comment: Do any of the prefixes other than `-khtml-` and `-webkit-` even exist for CSS masks? I've never heard of any other engine implementing them - CSS masks were proprietary to WebKit for a long time before finally being proposed as a standard.

Comment: For an automatic prefixing solution I strongly recommend Lea Verou's -prefix-free, although it's JavaScript-based it has access to the browser's knowledge of prefixes and can therefore handle all cases automatically without you needing to hardcode anything.

Comment: The [Masking module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1) says that the masking properties are in fact properties, although I'm not sure how WebKit chose to implement them prior to standardizing them (knowing WebKit, it *could* certainly have implemented them as values of `background`).